# Foreign key is not being retrieved

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

```
var student = _context.Appointments.Include(r => r.Request).SingleOrDefault(appo => appo.AppointmentUniqueId == id);
```

[image: Valid XHTML]

Comment: Share the relevant code of how you are currently rendering the input element and it's value.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a lot of information to work on, but it looks like the textbox is bound to `Request` instead of `Request.Id`